# Android debug builds perform much much worse than release builds

Tags: android

I'm not sure when I started to notice this (I would say sometime this year likely?) but I noticed the debug builds of my Android app perform extremely poorly compared to the release builds. I am not attaching the debugger, I am just building the debug version and then installing it on a device.

The reason why this is a big issue is because it makes is very difficult to judge whether app performance is degrading and how the app actually performs for an end user.

Has anyone else run into this and does anyone know of any possible causes?

**More information**

- My main test device is a Pixel 5 running Android 13 (it lagged even when it was running Android 12)
- The debug build appears to run smoother on a Pixel 3 despite it being a less performant device. This device is running Android 12.

Comment: This is unanswerably vague.  What isn't performing as well?  Memory use, CPU use, networking speed, other?  WHat have you measured the difference to be?  Have you run a profiler?  There's no data here for us to help with.

Comment: Here's a video of a side-by-side comparison between a pixel 3 (left) and pixel 5 (right). Both are running the debug build. You can see FPS lag on the right: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6uEB0RyT4A. On the release build both devices can run the app smoothly with 0 lag. I can run the profiler this afternoon, I'm out at the moment. To me it's obviously CPU lag but it could be something weird.

Comment: The performance difference seems to be huge. The app is almost incapable of smooth scrolling on a debug build on a Pixel 5 (A higher end device) yet the app scrolls smoothly even when fast swiping on a Moto G Power 2021 (a low end device). I've also disabled Pixel 5's 90 fps capability so it's locked at 60 max.

Comment: I've also noticed that my app became unusable in debug builds recently, they must have broken something, seems like the issue with RecyclerView only, when the layouts are inflating it takes forever.

Comment: Huh that is an interesting observation. I didn't realize this was only recycler views. I might do some tests to confirm. Maybe this can help me narrow down the cause. What is perplexing is that this only affects one device out of my 5 test devices. I'm not sure what could cause that other than some device specific OS issue?

Comment: Ok I finally ran some tests. I installed the same debug build on both a Moto G Power (2021) and the Pixel 5. I then did a CPU trace just scrolling up and down on the main page. The Pixel 5 lagged like crazy but the Moto G was smooth. The CPU trace revealed that the Pixel 5 spent 2-3x less time in the render thread and also on the main thread vs the Moto G. This indicates that CPU performance is fine on the Pixel 5.

Comment: I then enabled "Profile HWUI rendering" on both devices and scrolled up and down on the home screen. The Moto G Power's graph was very calm, bars would hover around 33% most of the time when scrolling, never going above half. On the Pixel 5, bars would go to around 80% - 90% when scrolling. From what I understand this graph represents the time it took to draw a frame. This indicates the Pixel 5 was way slower at drawing frames on debug builds and I have no idea why.